# can constant weight codes achieve channel capacity

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

Can a sequence of constant weight linear codes achieve channel capacity on Additive White Gaussian Noise channel? (by a sequence achieving capacity I mean a sequence of linear codes of increasing length and whose rate converges to capacity)